# using a single query to call multiple queries using apollo react hooks

Tags: graphql

I am new to this graphql, so what i am trying to achieve here is, i need to call two queries parallelly basically combining the queries and get the loading at a single time.

here i have seperated the queries and using two loading state, i need to combine it like compose.

The use case is, user clicks on the button on the button click i will pass the id, and hit both queries and get the list of data

```
 <Button
      text="Details"
      onClick={() => {
        getNames({ variables: { location_id: Number(location_id) } });
        getSchools({ variables: { location_id: Number(location_id) } });
      }}
    >
```

---

```
const [getNames, { loading: namesLoading, data: namesData }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_NAMES
  );
  const [
    getSchools,
    { loading: schoolsLoading, data: schoolsData },
  ] = useLazyQuery(GET_SCHOOLS);
```

---

```
const GET_NAMES = gql`
  query get_names($location_id: Int!) {
    get_names(location_id: $location_id) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

const GET_SCHOOLS = gql`
  query get_schools($location_id: Int!) {
    get_schools(location_id: $location_id) {
      schools {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

With splitting i am able to see the data, i am using "@apollo/react-hooks" to get the data with useLazyQuery, how can i achieve with this a single query. So instead of multiple loading , error data i can have a single one

Didn't find any compose hook from this library

Comment: just join queries, not hooks ... GET_NAMES_AND_SCHOOLS ? test in graphiql/playground - `query someName($location_id: Int!)) { get_names(location_id: $location_id){ id name } get_shools(location_id: $location_id){ id name }`

Comment: sure let me try xadm